# Insert data into a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am stuck in a simple problem. I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array ( productcode => 218133, categoryid => 315, color => red )
$array2 = (10,220)
```

How to merge this two arrays to have the below result?

```
$array1 = array ( productcode => 218133, categoryid => array (315, 10, 220),         color => red )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array ( 'productcode' => 218133, 'categoryid' => 315, 'color' => 'red' );
$array2 = array (10,220);

$array1['categoryid'] = array_merge((array)$array1['categoryid'], $array2);
print_r($array1);
```

> [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RCHjZ)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function here.
>
> Please note that both the parameters must be of **type array.**

So, first, we can declare an array variable **$category_id** and store the current categoryid within the array.

**$array2** is the array which needs to be appended to the categoryid field.

So, we can apply merge function on these two.

```
$category_id[] = $array1['categoryid'];
$array1['categoryid'] = array_merge($category_id, $array2);
```